# bigquery transpose and concatenate for each record

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, concatenation, transpose

I want to achieve the following transformation.
I have last_name stored in a repeated record as follows.

[data before transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2JPZ.png)

I want to achieve the following.
[data after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcgAk.png)

Example with sample data created.

```
create or replace table t1.cte1 as
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 as id,'eren' AS last_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as id,'yilmaz' AS last_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as id,'kaya' AS last_name
)
SELECT id,ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(last_name)) AS last_name_rec
FROM t1
GROUP BY id;

with test as (
select x.id, x.lname_agg,y.last_name  from
(
select id, STRING_AGG(h.last_name,' ') lname_agg FROM
  t1.cte1
  LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(last_name_rec) AS h
  group by id
  ) x,
  (select id,h.last_name last_name  FROM
  t1.cte1
  LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(last_name_rec) AS h
  group by last_name,id) y
) select id ,sp.string_flatten_dedup( lname_agg,' ') concat_last_name, last_name from test;
```

I'm not sure either if I should store it as an array instead of a concatenated field but it would be good to know how to achieve both.
[storing the concat_last_name as an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9brRC.png)

I have achieved the first transformation as follows but I had to dedup the concatenated field with a function I wrote.
I'm sure there is a much better way of achieving this.

```
       with test as (
select x.id id, x.lname_agg,y.last_name  from 
(
select id, STRING_AGG(h.last_name,' ') lname_agg FROM
  small_test
  LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(last_name_rec) AS h
  group by id
  ) x,
  (select id,h.last_name last_name  FROM
  small_test
  LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(last_name_rec) AS h group by last_name,id) y
) select id ,sp.string_flatten_dedup( lname_agg,' ') concat_last_name, last_name from test;
```

The function.
**string_flatten_dedup**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
sp.string_flatten_dedup(string_value string,
    delim string) AS
(
                            ARRAY_TO_STRING
                                (ARRAY(SELECT distinct string_value
                                       FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_value, delim)) AS string_value
                                       order by string_value desc, string_value),
                                 delim)
);
```

before using function.
[intermediate results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fi4I.png)

Final result after applying dedup function.
[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASzUU.png)

Updated table structure.
[t1.ccte1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah4aP.png)

Yours works but I got the table structure incorrect when I first posted.

```sql
create or replace table t1.cte2 as
with your_table as (
  select 1 id, ['brown', 'smith', 'jones'] last_name union all 
  select 2, ['ryan', 'murphy']
) select id, ln as last_name,
   array_to_string(last_name, ',') as concat_last_name,
from your_table, unnest(last_name) ln;

select id, ln as last_name,
   array_to_string(last_name, ',') as concat_last_name,
from t1.cte2, unnest(last_name) ln;

--fails as its not the structure I thought it was cte1 is different then cte2
select id, ln.last_name
   --array_to_string(last_name, ',') as concat_last_name,
from t1.cte1, unnest(last_name_rec) ln;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, ln as last_name, 
   array_to_string(last_name, ',') as concat_last_name,
from your_table, unnest(last_name) ln
```

if applied to sample data in your question [data before transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2JPZ.png)

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 id, ['brown', 'smith', 'jones'] last_name union all 
  select 2, ['ryan', 'murphy']
)
```

output is

[image]

In case if you want last names as an array - you already have this array - see below for how to use it

```
select id, ln as last_name, 
  last_name as concat_last_name,
from your_table, unnest(last_name) ln
```

with output

[image]

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: With the table I created, sorry for changing the names.

Comment: actual names do not matter  - right? the structure/schema of input and expected output does! so have you tried?

Comment: yep I tried the following.

```select id, ln as last_name,
      array_to_string(last_name, ',') as concat_last_name,
   from t1.cte1, unnest(last_name_rec) ln;```

And got an error. No matching signature for function ARRAY_TO_STRING for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY, STRING, [STRING]);

Comment: try with the sample data from your original question as per image you provided - I added it to my answer!

Comment: I think I may have put the incorrect table structure in my example. This is what it should look like. I'll copy image to the main thread.

Comment: I fully answered your original question as it was! and usually do not participate in follow up changes like you are doing here ...

Comment: Your works but I got the table structure incorrect when I first posted. 

```sql

Comment: I'll accept your answer and post a new question, my bad.